# Autoresizing issue in interface builder

Tags: ios, ipad, autoresizingmask

I have set autoresizing property for a search bar in xib(for iPad) as shown:

Now:

i think i should set some property in mainView of interface builder, but dont know, which property, if you have any suggestions, please share it.

if i remove both the middle one and right line then i get something like this:

Comment: +1 for nice explanation.

Comment: My guess - it's related to autolayouts. try to disable autolayout for that nib and see if it works.

Comment: Use autolayout property is already disabled.

Comment: I'm not in a situation where I can test it at the minute, but try adding flexible space between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove right red line from XIB autoresizing View as following image shows:--

[image]

Or try removing autolayout

[image]

**DONE**

**PORTRAIT MODE**
[image: PORTRAIT MODE]
**LANDSCAPE MODE**
[image: LANDSCAPE MODE]